# How to open a program (*.exe) in Window by Robot Framework - AutoIT

Tags: robotframework

I'm having trouble with opening a external Window program by Robot framework-Autoit.

Here is my code:

```
Notepad++
    Run     notepad++.exe

Or,

Notepad++
        Run     notepad++.exe        C:\Program Files\Notepad++
```

The error displays as below

```
Notepad++                                                             | FAIL |
Failed to run FileName='notepad++.exe', WorkingDir='C:\Program Files\'
```

But for internal Window program is Notepad, Paint - work OK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely the problem is simply that notepad++ isn't in your PATH. If you have notepad++ installed in the default location, try running this complete test case:

```
*** Settings ***
| Library | AutoItLibrary

*** Variables ***
| ${notepad++} | C:\\Program Files\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe

*** Test Cases ***
| Example
| | Run | ${notepad++}
```

If that works, it confirms that notepadd++ simply isn't in your PATH.  You can either hard-code the path into your test cases or keywords like in the above example, or you can edit your PATH to include the directory where Notepad++ is installed.

Comment: Thank, it works as expected. So, what is exactly problem ? Is the Notepad++ folder not in SYSTEM PATH ?

Comment: @LittleChicken: I'm glad it helped. I see you've asked almost a dozen questions but haven't accepted any answers. Are you aware that you should accept the answer that best helps you? Sometimes people will be hesitant to help someone who asks a lot of questions but never accepts any answers. For more information see http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @LittleChicken: yes, like I wrote in the answer, this confirms that notepadd++ isn't in your PATH.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your problem is with the PATH to your executable. In your first attempt you don't give a path at all and in the second you didn't surround it by double quotes to contain the space.

Put double quotes around your path

```
"C:\Program Files\Notepad++"
```

Comment: Also try your suggestion "C:\Program Files\Notepad++", but the error is below:

================
Notepad++                                                             | FAIL |
Failed to run FileName='notepad++.exe', WorkingDir='"C:Program FilesNotepad++"'"

Comment: Try... DIR "C:\Program Files\Notepad++.exe"

Comment: The error message you included above indicates you missed the slash between "Program Files" and "Notepad++" when you input the  "WorkingDir="

Comment: Yes, I also try the the path "C:\\Program Files\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe". But, it displays error 

"Notepad++                                                             | FAIL |
Failed to run FileName='notepad++.exe', WorkingDir='C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe'"

Answer (score 0):

after add AutoItLibrary,press"F5" and search"run".

you can see the description about"run".

the program you want to run,must have"\\"&"full path" (like Bryan Oakley said)

====== ========== =========

Arguments:[ FileName | WorkingDir= | Flag= ]

Direct wrapper for AutoIt's Run method.

This is required in order to do error code translation into exceptions for Robot Framework.

FileName:The full path of the program (EXE, BAT, COM, or PIF) to run (see remarks).

WorkingDir:The working directory. This is not the path to the program